# gradual GC calls

Tags: c#, arrays, memory-management, hashtable

Is there an effective way of returning part of an array's memory to the system?
i am using C# to iterate through a one large string arrays and a hashtable with (>100k elements) and I am setting the individual elements to null after i am finished with them. i've experimented with calling the garbage collector at various levels and throughout the loop but none of them return the memory to the system (a full call to the garbage collector and wait for pending finalizers causes my code to become extremely slow and unresponsive).
I've thought about splitting the array into n parts and call the gc after each part is finished but that seems messy

```
GC.Collect(1);
GC.Collect(2);
....
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect();
```

Comment: Probably the best thing to do is to let the GC do its job. Setting references to null is more than enough.

Comment: @HenkHolterman ok :) I figured it couldn't hurt to ask. if I don't get any answers i'll delete the question :)

Comment: Assuming there are no other live references to the objects.  Also, if they are sufficiently large they may be allocated on the large object heap and you could be seeing fragmentation.

Comment: @caseyr547, deleting a question is totally unnecessary...

Comment: @EdS. thanks that would make sense if they are on the large object heap would my idea about multiple arrays fix the memory leak?

Comment: @caseyr547: which memory leak? Nothing is being leaked, it's just a matter of how eager the GC is to reclaim the memory

Comment: @HenkHolterman i dont have a string 20 million thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @jalf your right its not quite a leak it just feels like one for a few seconds :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just let the garbage collector do its thing. The most efficient approach is exactly what the GC already does: defer collections until they actually have to be done. That way it doesn't have to do more collections than necessary, and all the memory reclaiming work can be batched together into relatively few collect calls, so it doesn't have to traverse the object graph more often than necessary.

Just make sure to clear any references to the object, so you don't accidentally keep it alive longer than necessary, but as long as you do that, you shouldn't really need to do anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Under all but some very specific and exceptional circumstances, the best policy is to let the garbage collector operate on its own schedule.  It's a highly tuned piece of software with much more knowledge of the inner workings of the CLR than you or I have, and nearly always will make better decisions than we will.

If you're concerned about the memory consumed by object after you're done with them, you can null out the individual array elements as you finish your work with them (potentially making the objects available to be collected sooner).

More to the point, is there a need to keep all of your data in memory at once?  Is it possible to load up only a bit at a time - say, to read incrementally from a file?  If so, you definitely have the option of replacing your array with an `IEnumerable<T>`, allowing you to lazily load data as needed and forget about it automatically once you're done with it.  This approach is guaranteed to keep your memory consumption down, at the expense of some slight additional computation.

Answer (score 0):

If you store strings in an array, they'll all stay in memory while you iterate through them.

The actual iteration will not increase memory pressure a lot: any new objects you create will be efficiently garbage collected.

For the specific case of an array, you could set the array entries to `null` once you have read them. I would reccomend against it: If you survive the start of the iteration without out of memory issues, you probably will survive the rest as well. 
Do make sure to null **all** the references to the array once you don't need it anymore. While you are debugging, you can add a GC.Collect() at the point where you think the array is no longer referenced. You should observe a large drop in allocated memory. If this does not happen, you have more reference to the array, or references to the array content, elsewhere.

For hashtables, this approach won't work at all. You can't safely remove entries from hashtables while iterating over them.

Now, if you are using hashtables, this implies you don't really care about the order of the items. In that case, you could rework your algorithm to process it as the data is read, without retaining it in an array or hashtable.